# how to get integer value from Ms Excel to java

Tags: java, excel

I imported Apache.POI package and want to get integer value from Excel cell to Java console.
I know how get the string value from excel cell to Java console

```
System.out.println(sh1.getRow(0).getCell(2).getRichStringCellValue().toString());
```

but i don't know how to get integer value.
Please help me.

The code is below.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.WorkbookUtil; 

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

public class Excel {

    public static void main(String[] arg){
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

        Sheet sh1 = workbook.createSheet("sheet1");

        Cell cell1 = sh1.createRow(0).createCell(0);
        Cell cell2 = sh1.createRow(0).createCell(1);
        Cell cell3 = sh1.createRow(0).createCell(2);


        cell1.setCellValue(100);
        cell2.setCellValue(200);
        cell3.setCellFormula("A1+B1");


        //Here!! I want to get integer value of cell3
        System.out.println(sh1.getRow(0).getCell(2).....);

        ..........
    }

}
```

thanks

Comment: Did you take a look at [Busy Developers' Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)?

Comment: i have to look that up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `getNumericCellValue()`. See the documentation of [HSSFCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#getNumericCellValue()) for more information.

Comment: i tried .. but there is error msg with 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Excel.Excel.main(Excel.java:36)"

Comment: @imhyung Try to find out wich value is null. sh1, sh1.getRow(0) ... it has nothing to do with the numeric value.

Comment: and 'getNumbericCellValue()' returns double, so i also made return value to double. but still shows the same error msg.

Comment: Looks like `sh1.getRow(0)` or `sh1.getRow(0).getCell(2)` is null. So you get the NPE

Comment: `cell3.getNumbericCellValue()`is working instead `sh1.rownumber.cellnumber.getNumbericCellValue()` Thanks man!!